# Store locator not working after updating to https

Tags: magento-1.9, stores, google-map

I updated my website to https yesterday, but today I saw that my Storelocator isn't working anymore. It tells me that the 'store list undefined'. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

These errors frequently happen because of [mixed content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content) errors. Confirm that your Javascript console is clear of mixed content errors.

If the issue happens because of mixed content, then likely the request to the store locator service is not secure. Perhaps you can simply update the URL in the request to use HTTPS. Or, perhaps the service provider would have to update their software to provide a secure response.